# Criteria-API - Hibernate generates unwanted order by statement

Tags: hibernate, orm, criteria-api

I have a fairly complex data model and consequently a fairly complex query (using criteria API):

This is my criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(MyClass.class);

criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                    .setFetchMode("pricedBy", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .setFetchMode("canceledBy", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .setFetchMode("product", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .setFetchMode("product.underlyings", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .setFetchMode("product.tradedBy", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .setFetchMode("product.requestedBy", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .setFetchMode("fileUploads", FetchMode.JOIN)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("issuer.id", issuerCompanyId));

criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("product.id"));

criteria.setFirstResult(pagingParams.getDisplayStart())
            .setMaxResults(pagingParams.getDisplayLength());

 List<MyClass> result =  criteria.list()
```

Nothing more, nothing skipped.

If I now look at the generated SQL (pretty huge statement), it ends like this:

```
...and this_.issuer_id=? order by underlying12_.ric asc, this_.product_id desc
```

And here is my problem: The **order by underlying12_.ric asc** is completely unwanted, and of course it results in a wrong ordering of my result.

I have absolutely no clue where the statement comes from and how I can get rid of it. Any help is welcome :-)

**Update:** Found the `order by` statement in my very own code. This question can certainly be closed.

Comment: Have you tried using standard (and portable) JPA syntax for your criteria query?

Comment: I'm doing that right now. But this is a major refactoring and I'd definitely prefer to understand what's going wrong with the criteria query. Can't be that I'm the first one who tries to order some joined entities, can't it?

Comment: Uhm.. it sounds unlikely that you are the first one that tries to order joined entities. Anyway, refactoring your query to portable JPA doesn't seem a mayor task and if you need guidance I can help.

Comment: Thanks for your help - let me just mention that I skipped a couple of hundred lines of code that generate the criteria based on various filter, sorting and paging requirements :-)

Comment: Wow. Glad to know that you have been able to find the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. Just discovered this mapping from product to underlying:

@OrderBy(value="ric")
private Set underlyings = new HashSet();